# Alternative names for items in logistic regression

Tags: logistic, terminology

I am reading Applied Logistic Regression by Hosmer and Lemeshow.

In chapter 1, they defined $D$ as $-2\ln(\text{likelihood ratio})$, which $D$ is also known as the *deviance*, and $G$ as 
$$D(\text{model without the variable}) - D(\text{model with the variable}).$$

I wonder if $G$ also has an alternative name.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$G$ is also named *likelihood ratio test*, I found it in the book shortly afterwards.

Comment: Strictly, G is the likelihood ratio test *statistic*.